# php jquery ajax checkbox validation

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when ajax is called data is not passed . wen send function is called validat() is assigned to valid variable after validation the return is true however ajax is not called to pass  through POST into php file for updates.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" > 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" >
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="res1"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language1"   value="English" >English<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language2" value="French" >French<br/>
            <input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language3" value="German" onclick="validate();">German<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="language" id="language4" value="Latin" >Latin<br/>
            <button type="button" onclick="send();" >Send</button>
        </div>
        <div id="res"></div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>

<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>

function send(){
    var valid = validate();
    if(valid){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'process.php',
            data:{fruit:fruit},
            success:function(msg){
                    $("#res1").html(msg);
            },
            error:''
        });
    }
}
function validate(){
    var valid = true;

    var fruit = Array();
    $('input[name="language"]:checked').each(function(){
        fruit.push(this.value);
     });        
    if((fruit == '')){
        $("#res1").html("Atleast one checkbox      requiered").css({'color':'red'});
        $("#dem-res").html("Required").css({'color':'red'});
        valid = false;
    }else if(!(fruit == '')){
        $("#res1").html("");
        $("#dem-res").html("");
     }
    return valid;
}

</script>
```

Comment: data:{'fruit':fruit} and fruit must be any variable name var fruit = "name";

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ajax code with

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'process.php',
        data:{'fruit':fruit},
        success:function(msg){
                $("#res1").html(msg);
        },
        error:''
    });
```

You have error on sending data. Which is in incorrect format.i.e. Missing quotes.
depending upon type of response sending form server. It is possible to help more.If you are just `echo` some html code in server i think this is enough.

Comment: I think you missed dataType there.

Comment: what type of data you want to return from server.

Comment: if `json` use `dataType:json` and use `JSON.parse()` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You missing variable:

```
var fruit_name = "orange";
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'process.php',
        data:{"fruit" : fruit_name},
        success:function(msg){
                $("#res1").html(msg);
        },
        error:''
    });
```